# sqlmap cannot find a dispatched vulnerability

Tags: web-application, sql-injection, sqlmap

I have a known sqli vulnerability that I'd like to try out with sqlmap in a web application; however, I don't believe sqlmap is able to figure this one out. Here's how the system works:

- Inject on a given parameter, s, in Thread 1.
- Thread 1 dispatches the information to a second thread.
  Thread 1 returns an HTML message immediately always with a status of
  "Pending"
- Thread 2 now executes the sqli and writes a file to a location in the
  web site I can look up. It also returns a Success message.

I cannot directly call the private method that Thread 2 executes, so I need to start with the dispatcher. However, I believe sqlmap can only find that this is a successful injection if it could read the outcome of thread 2. Does anyone have any idea how I could get sqlmap to understand this sequence?

Comment: Is there a reason why sqlmap is the required tool to verify?

Comment: No. I suppose not. I'm just most comfortable with it and I'd be happier if I knew how to make it work in this case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This appears to be some type of what is known as [Second Order SQL Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection#Second_Order_SQL_Injection).

Even if Thread 1 writes to a queue instead of to a DB, as the injection does not happen as a direct result of it, sqlmap cannot be used to exploit the vulnerability.

Sqlmap looks for error messages in responses or differences in timing (for blind SQL injection) to determine whether a page is vulnerable. Since these types of attack will usually be undetectable using these methods (unless it *does* alter the original page - but then you've got a latency issue), sqlmap would not be able to exploit it.

Comment: Great. Thank you for the link. I finally got it working by standing up an intercepting proxy and making the second request before returning to sqlmap. E.g. sqlmap->proxy->server->proxy->server->proxy->sqlmap. It took a bunch of finagling, but tricks sqlmap into working correctly. I'm marking you correct anyways, since my way is a bit of a nasty hack.